# Trouble with logical "and" query in mongomapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongomapper

I am using mongo db for a model in my rails application, and when I execute

```
Model.where(:$or => [{:field1 => true}, {:field2 => true}])
```

produces plucky query

```
#<Plucky::Query $or: [{:field1=>true}, {:field2=>true}], transformer: #<Proc:0xa4b1c5c@/home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:79 (lambda)>>
```

performs OR operation and fetches the correct results, ie, field1 or field2 is true but

```
Model.where(:$and => [{:field1 => true}, {:field2 => true}])
```

produces plucky query

```
#<Plucky::Query $and: {"$in"=>[{:field1=>true}, {:field2=>true}]}, transformer: #<Proc:0xa435120@/home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:79 (lambda)>>
```

doesn't perform the AND operation, instead it throws error

> Mongo::OperationFailure Exception: $and expression must be a nonempty
>   array

DETAILS

> Rails version: 3.1, 
>   Mongo version: 2.0.0, 
>   mongo_mapper gem version: 0.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to upgrade MongoMapper.  `$and` support was added in plucky 0.4.x, which MongoMapper uses as of version 0.10.1.

[This commit](https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/commit/85f5a6b05e2a0334124a23e40d3453d8f364ffe7) added `$and` support to plucky and is part of plucky 0.4.2 and greater.

[This commit](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/commit/c66285d15441f2c501d6df00a557de6e694cc3d0) updated MongoMapper to use plucky 0.4.x and is part of MM 0.10.1 and greater.